# Best way to save and load DataGridView Data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I hope someone can help me because I didn't find a good solution for this.

I am creating a Windows Form App where I have a DataGridView.
I enter data into this DataGirdView in different ways (from textBox, listBox, buttons... etc) this works fine.

When I finish the work with the data, I want to press a button and save the DataGridView to a file. When I open the Windows Form App the Data should automatically load the saved data in my DataGridView and I can work with the data again.

**My question is, what is the best/cleanest/easiest way to do this? I'm pretty new to this, but I want to do it the best way.** (and sorry for bad English)

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: You want to save your data, which is presented in a datagrid, but you "can't" save a datagrid, just the data. Forget about the datagrid for a while. Study the MVC pattern. Design a data structure to hold your data. Research how to persist this data structure to a file. You could use simple IO operations, CSV files, XML/Binary serialization, JSON, etc. This is assuming you are not using a database.